# mvc3 validation check if property values differ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

in MVC3 you can add validation to models to check if properties match like so:

```
public string NewPassword { get; set; }

[Compare("NewPassword", 
ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

Is there a way to check that two properties differ like in the following make-believe code?

```
[CheckPropertiesDiffer("OldPassword", 
ErrorMessage = "Old and new passwords cannot be the same")]
public string OldPassword { get; set; }

public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what you could use in the model:

```
public string OldPassword

[NotEqualTo("OldPassword", ErrorMessage = "Old and new passwords cannot be the same.")]
public string NewPassword { get; set; }
```

And then define the following custom attribute:

```
public class NotEqualToAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private const string defaultErrorMessage = "{0} cannot be the same as {1}.";

    private string otherProperty;

    public NotEqualToAttribute(string otherProperty) : base(defaultErrorMessage)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(otherProperty))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("otherProperty");
        }

        this.otherProperty = otherProperty;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format(ErrorMessageString, name, otherProperty);
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            PropertyInfo otherPropertyInfo = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty(otherProperty);

            if (otherPropertyInfo == null)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(string.Format("Property '{0}' is undefined.", otherProperty));
            }

            var otherPropertyValue = otherPropertyInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

            if (otherPropertyValue != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(otherPropertyValue.ToString()))
            {
                if (value.Equals(otherPropertyValue))
                {
                    return new ValidationResult(this.FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
                }
            }
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }        
}
```

Comment: @Dangerous I added this to my project but the error is not showing when both fields are same. Can you help me out?

Comment: @Mohit - There could be a number of possibilities as to why it may not be working for yourself.  I would suggest you post this as a new question on SO, detailing what you are trying to achieve and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 6):

I would do checking in the controller.

In controller:

```
if(model.ConfirmPassword == model.OldPassword ){
  ModelState.AddModelError("ConfirmPassword", "Old and new passwords cannot be the same");
}
```

In View:

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("ConfirmPassword")
```

Hope this helps

Comment: +1 thanks this way works well and is the simplest solution here -- but I will go with Dangerous' answer as the NotEqualTo ValidationAttribute solution will be reusable elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You could also implement class level validation like in the description here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/10/class-level-model-validation-with-ef-code-first-and-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

Basically you implement the Validate method of IValidatableObject and can access any properties you want.

```
public class MyClass : IValidateableObject
{
    public string NewPassword { get; set; } 
    public string OldPassword { get; set; } 

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext context)
    {
       if (NewPassword == OldPassword)
          yield return new ValidationResult("Passwords should not be the same");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is already a built-in attribute providing this functionality.
The best approach would be to create your own custom attribute like described in detail there:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CustomValidation.aspx

Comment: thanks, but i can't see how to compare two values with that example - is it possible?